# How to effectively loop within groups in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a table like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'date':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] ,'high':[10,9,8,8,7,6,7,8,9,10],'low':[9,7,6,5,2,1,2,1,8,9],'stock':['A']*5 + ['B']*5})
```

| date | high | low | stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 9 | A |
| 2 | 9 | 7 | A |
| 3 | 8 | 6 | A |
| 4 | 8 | 5 | A |
| 5 | 7 | 2 | A |
| 6 | 6 | 1 | B |
| 7 | 7 | 2 | B |
| 8 | 8 | 1 | B |
| 9 | 9 | 8 | B |
| 10 | 10 | 9 | B |

For each day of each stock, I would like to know what is the max difference between “high” of today and low (after or today). For example, on date 1, stock A high price is $10. I look at date 1-5 and find maximum difference between high and low is on date 5. Result will be 10-2=8 for date 1. On date 2, I should only look at date 2 afterwards for "low".

Results:

| date | high | low | stock | diff_high_low |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 9 | A | 8 |
| 2 | 9 | 7 | A | 7 |
| 3 | 8 | 6 | A | 6 |
| 4 | 8 | 5 | A | 6 |
| 5 | 7 | 2 | A | 5 |
| 6 | 6 | 1 | B | 5 |
| 7 | 7 | 2 | B | 6 |
| 8 | 8 | 1 | B | 7 |
| 9 | 9 | 8 | B | 1 |
| 10 | 10 | 9 | B | 1 |

I am currently using a for-loop and it works. It is really slow on my 1 million+ rows table. Is there a better way to do it?

My current method:

```
diff_high_low=[]
for gname, g in df.groupby('stock'):
    rows = g.shape[0]
    for i in range(0,rows):
            diff_high_low.append(max( g['high'].iloc[i] - g['low'].iloc[i:rows,]))
df['diff_high_low'] = diff_high_low
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need `groupby` with `cummin`

```
df['diff_high_low'] = df['high'] - df.iloc[::-1].groupby('stock')['low'].cummin()
Out[273]: 
0    8
1    7
2    6
3    6
4    5
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    1
9    1
dtype: int64
```